# XML to JSON (x2js) in angularJS to get HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, xml

I'm trying to convert xml to json for processing in AngularJS can't make it work.

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/16tph2sx/)

I guess i need to put source for x2js

```
<script src="bower_components/x2js/xml2json.js"></script>

<script src="bower_components/angular-x2js/src/x2js.js"></script>
```

but don't know where to put in jsFiddle

As output i need json in form of HTML table

Comment: You have to add it under "External Resources" in the left pane.

Comment: @JiaJian i did that but still can't make it work

Comment: Check a working jsFiddle like this one http://jsfiddle.net/abdmob/gtLBx/15/ and also you can try to use a x2js wrapper for Angular https://github.com/cesarbarone/angular-x2js

Comment: I've updated your jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/16tph2sx/7/

Comment: @beaver thanks! but html table isn't come out of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another jsFiddle which convert your XML into JSON and via ng-repeat shows it in an HTML table:

http://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/n8ov74oe/

Note that the JSON obtained from you XML has the following form:

```
var json = {
    "Table" : {
        "Row" : [{
                "Cell" : [{
                        "_cellWidth" : "937",
                        "__text" : "Cat. No."
                    }, ...
                ],
                "_cellSize" : "9"
                },
                {
                "Cell" : [{
                        "_cellWidth" : "937",
                        "__text" : "11"
                    }, ...
                ],
                "_cellSize" : "9"
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

so real data are in `json.Table.Row`